# How to iterate backwards and forwards through an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have an array and direction variable for example:

```
var fruits = ["apple","banana","cherry"];
var direction = 1; 
//1 => forward; -1 => backwards;
```

then to call it I might say

```
index = **SOME MATHS HERE** 
var fruit = fruits[index]
```

So the aim is to have a loop that can go backwards and forwards through the array. I want to have a for loop that iterates through the array. I know I can do this using an if loop saying
`if(direction < 0){//backwards}` kind of thing but that would mean two lots of code when I can make it one using a clever maths operation to iterate through it.

Comment: What else is the loop meant to do?

Comment: The idea is to run a set of animations in order for how the object should be animated i.e. change the height then change the width then change the border etc. If the user wants to abruptly reverse the animation it can loop back through the array of animations and go backwards. For example say we are doing the border change, the user reverses the animation, the width should be executed then the height.

Comment: This is closed at this time, but out of curiosity I wanted to answer the "SOME MATHS HERE" question specifically, and make a more compact (if less efficient) example than in the existing answers.  So here's what I came up with:  https://jsfiddle.net/psxfzL23/

The "maths" are `Math.abs((fruits.length - 1) * direction - i)` (assuming that `i` is the incrementor in a for loop from 0 to fruits.length-1).  Perhaps counter-intuitively I'm using a value of `0` for ascending and `1` for descending in var `dir`.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this would work:

```
var fruits = ["apple","banana","cherry"];
var direction = 1;  // or -1

var i = direction > 0 ? 0 : fruits.length - 1,
    stop = direction > 0 ? fruits.length : -1;
for (; i != stop; i += direction)
    console.log(i, fruits[i]);
```

```js
var fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"];

function iterate(direction) {
  var results = $("#results").empty();
  var i = direction > 0 ? 0 : fruits.length - 1,
    stop = direction > 0 ? fruits.length : -1;
  for (; i != stop; i += direction)
    $("<span>").text(i + ": " + fruits[i] + "\n").appendTo(results);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="iterate(1)">Forward</button>
<button onclick="iterate(-1)">Backward</button>
<pre id="results" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make a function.

```
var fruits = ["apple","banana","cherry"];
var direction = 1;

function iterate(arr, direction, callback){
    if(direction === 1){
        console.log("Forwards");
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            //Iterate through array regularly
            if(callback !== undefined){
                callback(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        console.log("Backwards");
        for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            //Iterate through array backwards
            if(callback !== undefined){
                callback(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

iterate(fruits, direction, function(a){
    console.log(a);
});

iterate(fruits, -direction, function(a){
    console.log(a);
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsj200/vdtP8/1/)

Comment: This would work, but is exactly what is trying to be avoided by the OP.  Also, you forgot to call the function.

Comment: There's no reason to make this overly difficult.

Comment: Yes, but for example, let's say that the for loop took each value and did some long, complicated process on it.  That process would need to be written twice or use another method in order for it to work properly.  I'm pretty sure that's why it is trying to be avoided.

Comment: Pass an anonymous callback function that does what you need (see edit).

Answer (score 1):

see http://jsfiddle.net/ZfL24/1/

```
var fruits = ["apple","banana","cherry"];
var direction = 1; 
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    var fruit = fruits[direction === 1 ? i : fruits.length - (i + 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic "bi-directional" loop:

```
function bdLoop (step, amount[, additional arguments]) {
    var n = (step < 0) ? amount - 1 : 0,
        x, xstep = Math.abs(step);
    for (x = 0; x < amount; x += xstep, n += step) {
        // x always equals to 0 .. amount stepped by xstep
        // n equals to 0 .. amount or amount .. 0 stepped by step, depends on direction (±step)
    }
    return[ results];
}
```

Within the loop you can refer to variables in the outer scope, handle passed arguments, and also pass a function reference and call the passed function etc.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGWuG/).

Answer (score 0):

How about reversing the array conditionally so it's not as much code since you seem to want to avoid that:

```
if (direction < 0) {
    fruits.reverse();
}
```

Then, use your for loop and it will go backwards or forwards depending on the value of direction.